# How to move HTTPClient to async Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having trouble with an method I am moving to an AsyncTask.  I have the doInBackground complete but I need to move the rest of the method into onPostExecute...I Just don't know how to.

Here is my original Method.

```
private void ShowFuelStopAndRoute(String location) throws IOException {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());  
    List<Address> addresses;

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0) {
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fillingstation);
        currentFuelLat= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
        currentFuellong= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
        LatLng toPostion = new LatLng(currentFuelLat, currentFuellong);
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        AsyncDoc asyncDoc = new AsyncDoc(MapViewActivity.this, currentLocation, toPostion, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }

        map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        Marker fuelMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPostion).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("Fueling Station, " + location));


    }
}
```

I move the following line into a different class and a Async Class

```
Document doc = md.getDocument(currentLocation, toPostion, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
```

And this has been replaced with :

```
return DALController.sharedInstance().getDocument(startLoc, endLoc, mode);
```

I have this much of the AsyncTask Complete as shown below:

```
    private class AsyncDoc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document > {

        public String mode;
        public LatLng startLoc;
        public LatLng endLoc;


        public AsyncDoc (Activity activity, LatLng startLoc, LatLng endLoc, String mode){

            this.startLoc = startLoc;
            this.endLoc = endLoc;
            this.mode = mode;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }

        private Activity activity;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            if (! (activity).isFinishing()) {
                this.dialog.show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected Document  doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return DALController.sharedInstance().getDocument(startLoc, endLoc, mode);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document  result) {

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }




        }

    }
```

But I need to make sure the rest of the code doesn't run until the doInBackground is complete:

```
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);

        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }

        map.addPolyline(rectLine);
        Marker fuelMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPostion).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title("Fueling Station, " + location));
```

How can I ensure the doInBackground completes before the rest of my showfuelstopandroute method completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I ensure the doInBackground completes before the rest of my
>   showfuelstopandroute method completes?

you should need to move all code inside `onPostExecute` which you want to execute after doInBackground execution complete. as:

```
@Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Document  result) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
         // do your work here after doInBackground execution
          ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(result);
          ....

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In an AsyncTask, the method onPostExecute() runs only after doInBackground() has completed. What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you can move the whole code which should be executed after the task in its postExecute-method.
Another method would be to let your activity have a Method for hat which the task can call in its onPostExecute()

Comment: What if I moved the whole showFuelStopRoute into the AsyncTask?